# cs50, Where is the int rank and voter increased?

Tags: c, cs50

I have a problem when running this code. It is from the CS50. I am confused how the integers
rank and voter which are inputs for this bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name) get increased. I do not see any rank++ nor voters, yet somehow when the code is executed it works correctly and their value is increased, when the loop for getting the vote is executed. Thank you very much

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


// Max voters and candidates
#define MAX_VOTERS 100
#define MAX_CANDIDATES 9

// preferences[i][j] is jth preference for voter i
int preferences[MAX_VOTERS][MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Candidates have name, vote count, eliminated status
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Numbers of voters and candidates
int voter_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);
void tabulate(void);
bool print_winner(void);
int find_min(void);
bool is_tie(int min);
void eliminate(int min);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: runoff [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX_CANDIDATES)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX_CANDIDATES);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    if (voter_count > MAX_VOTERS)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of voters is %i\n", MAX_VOTERS);
        return 3;
    }

    // Keep querying for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            // Record vote, unless it's invalid
            if (!vote(i, j, name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 4;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    // Keep holding runoffs until winner exists
    while (true)
    {
        // Calculate votes given remaining candidates
        tabulate();

        // Check if election has been won
        bool won = print_winner();
        if (won)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate last-place candidates
        int min = find_min();
        bool tie = is_tie(min);

        // If tie, everyone wins
        if (tie)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
            {
                if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate anyone with minimum number of votes
        eliminate(min);

        // Reset vote counts back to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            candidates[i].votes = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    for(int i = 0; 0 < candidate_count; i++)
    {
      
        if(strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
        preferences[voter][rank]++;
        return true;
        }
    }
    // TODO
    return false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any kind o debugging? Like [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)? Or using an actual debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values?

Comment: Those values are passed into the `vote` function here: `if (!vote(i, j, name))` The values passed in change on each iteration of the for  loops.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you ! I totally skipped that !

Comment: The function is called as "vote(i, j, name)" inside loops that increment i and j. The variable names "voter" and "rank" exist only inside the function itself.

Comment: What makes me wonder about this function, which works as you confirm. why could the author of the function not explain how what you observe is achieved. Maybe you are the author, maybe not, but whoever did write this should be able to explain. So, why do you need the help by StackOverflow?

Comment: But to actually help you (extending on the rubber ducking recommendation earlier....). If you can describe in more detail what makes you think that indeed "the integers rank and voter which are inputs for this bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name) get increased". What symptoms dou you have of that? Please go into more detail, because "the program works so they must be" is not precise enough. That does make the assumption that increasing those variable is actually necessary. But if you go into detail, like "I printed those values and as you can see in this output they do increase"...